# Network Image on CustomListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I have a custom list view with a list of Countries and their flags. I have managed to get the list of countries names in the list, but the whole list is 1 flag which is set in the XML.

I would like to get the list of flags implemented as well but am a bit lost as how i can go about getting the image into the list.

Please see my code below:

CountryAdapter.java

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CountryHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.search_results_row_list, parent, false);
        holder = new CountryHolder();
        holder.countryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_text);
        holder.countryFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_flag);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CountryHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.countryName.setText(countryArrayList.get(position).getCountryName());
//        holder.countryFlag.setImageResource(countryArrayList.get(position).getImgId());
    return convertView;
}
```

Network call:

```
public void getCountries(Activity activity) {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity.getApplicationContext());
    CustomNetwork jsObjRequest = new CustomNetwork(url, createRequestSuccessListener(), createRequestErrorListener());

    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}

//     Method called when there is an error in the network call
//    ----------------------------------------Error Listener for Request---------------------------------------
private Response.ErrorListener createRequestErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Networking", "Error is at: " + error.toString());
        }
    };
}

private Response.Listener<JSONArray> createRequestSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.i("Networking", "Response is: " + response.toString());
            countriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject tempObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String countryName = tempObject.getString("name");
                    String countryFlag = tempObject.getString("flag_32");  //This "flag_32" will return the name of the file on the website im hosting the file
                    countriesArrayList.add(new Countries(countryName, countryFlag));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            setCountriesArrayList(countriesArrayList);
            mCallBack.callBack();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Sorry i accidentally pressed enter before finishing the question

Comment: Done that (a few thousand times) before ;)

Comment: Have you done the image loading part from the url?

Comment: you need to download the images from server and save them somewhere before loading them into the ListView .

Comment: but i would prefer if it was saved to cache as apposed to disc, as this is just a test for something with many more images involved and saving to Disc would not be feesable

Comment: you can use library for that . example  : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader . This provides implementation for storing images in cache .

Comment: i will try that @WannaBeGeek and let you know, thanks